# orbit slider - remove progress bar from orbit slider

Tags: slideshow, zurb-foundation, progress, orbit

How can I remove or turn off the timer progress bar of the orbit slider?

Looked at all the custom settings but don't see anything that would do that.

Comment: I believe the "correct" way to do this is to set `$orbit-timer-show-progress-bar` to false in the SCSS settings. Unfortunately, I can't get this to have any effect. (hence not posting it as an answer).

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your stylesheet:

.orbit-timer { display:none;}

It will completely hide the progress bar, it will just be on a continuous loop.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the HTML file:

```
<ul data-orbit data-options="timer:false;">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

or inside the JS file:

```
$(document).foundation({
  orbit: {
    timer: false
  }
});
```

If you use Foundation 5, see the docs [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html), and in case of Foundation 4 [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/components/orbit.html). You can find the instructions about the JS-settings of Orbit at the end of the mentioned docs pages.

Comment: The problem with timer:false; is that it turns the time off completely so the images then won't rotate. I still want the images to rotate I just need to get rid of the progress bar in the upper right portion of the slider?

Comment: Try to add the following rule to your CSS file: `.orbit-timer { display:none; }`, and delete the `timer:false;` rule.